# POJO to Web Service through Controller in Spring Boot is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Spring Boot service client project. I have a JSP file, a POJO, Controller and Web Service classes. They are given below.

My problem is that whenever I call the WS from JSP through client Controller, it is not working. However, it is working when it gets called directly from the method. Also, it works when removing `@Valid` from service method.

**JSP file:**

```
<%@ page import="test.model.CardType" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!-- ... -->

<form:hidden path="id" />
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Card Number:</label></td>
                <td><form:input path="number" placeholder="Card Number" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <form:select path="type">
                    <form:options items="${cards}" />
                </form:select>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Year:</label></td>
                <td><form:input path="year" placeholder="Year" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Month:</label></td>
                <td><form:input path="month" placeholder="month" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Security Code:</label></td>
                <td><form:input path="code" placeholder="Code" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label></label></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

**Mapping Function:**

```
@PostMapping("/checkout")
public String checkOut(@ModelAttribute("card") Card card) {
    /** Card card2 = new Card(); //problem is in here: if I sent card2 it works, but not with card
    card2.setId(1);
    card2.setCode(123);
    card2.setMonth(123);
    card2.setNumber("1111222233334444");
    card2.setType(CardType.DEBIT_CARD);
    card2.setYear(1990);
    System.out.println("========= ====================================" + "\n" + card.getId() + "\n"
            + card.getCode() + "\n" + card.getMonth() + "\n" + card.getNumber() + "\n" + card.getYear() + "\n"
            + card.getType() + "-------------------------------");*/

    final String uri = "http://localhost:8090/cardservice";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Card result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, card, Card.class);
    System.out.println(result.getNumber() + "\n" + result.getType());

    return "redirect:/card/form";
}
```

**POJO:**

```
@Entity
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String number;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CardType type;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int code;

    // Getters/Setters

}
```

**Service:**

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/cardservice")
public Card getDetails(@Valid @RequestBody Card card, BindingResult br) {
    if(br.hasErrors()){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter valid credit card number");
    }

    return card;
}
```

In service, `Card` domain is the same as in client, but I used `@CreditCardNumber` to validate credit card number.

**Error:**

```
2016-11-22 00:18:37.784[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m501[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is     

org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null] with    
root cause
```

Comment: Can you provide the problem in details with logs?

Comment: i have updated my question .@mayankagrawal